# Filter queryset only where the user is added to ManyToManyFIeld

Tags: django

I want to return all leads that contain a current user. How to do it?

Models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Lead(models.Model):
    budget = models.IntegerField()
    buyer = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser)
```

What queryset is expected

```
Lead.objects.filter(buyer__have=request.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Lead.objects.filter(buyer=request.user)
```

this will make an `INNER JOIN`, and return only `Lead` objects where `request.user` is (*one of*) the `buyer`s.